# Attribute Error in Altered Sample API

Tags: python

I'm running this as part of a call to the api using the url. I dont know what I'm doing wrong - the terminal keeps saying I have an Attribute error where the '`Namespace`' object has no attribute to offset. I wanted to add search parameters "`offset, sort` and `category_filter`", but am not sure what I have to do to the `parser.add_argument`. I tried copying those that were in the sample code listed below, but it didnt seem to work. I'm a bit confused as to why that is...

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

```
parser.add_argument('-q', '--term', dest='term', default=DEFAULT_TERM,
                    type=str, help='Search term (default: %(default)s)')
parser.add_argument('-l', '--location', dest='location',
                    default=DEFAULT_LOCATION, type=str,
                    help='Search location (default: %(default)s)')
parser.add_argument('--offset', dest='offset', default=DEFAULT_OFFSET,
                    type=int, help='Search offset (default: %(default)s)')
parser.add_argument('--sort', dest='sort', default=DEFAULT_SORT,
                    type=int, help='Sear sort (default:%(default)s)')
parser.add_argument('--category_filter', dest='category_filter', default=DEFAULT_CATEGORY_FILTER,
                    type=str, help='Search category_filter (default: %(default)s)')

input_values = parser.parse_args()

try:
    query_api(input_values.term, input_values.location, input_values.offset, input_values.sort, input_values.category_filter)
except urllib2.HTTPError as error:
```

Comment: As the error says, you are trying to access an attribute `offset` with `input_values.offset` and there is no offset option defined.  If you fix that you'll start getting the same error complaining about a missing attribute `category_filter` since it is not defined either.

Comment: Have you tried `parser.add_argument('--offset', ...)`?

Comment: I have, but it encounters an error! it goes straight to HTTP error 400.

Comment: The sample originally had the first two parser.add_arguments for "term" and "location". I wanted to add offset, sort, and category_filter, but when I added them (as shown above), I run into an HTTP Error. I'm not particulary sure how to change the code. (also, theres a typo that i changed in spelling "Search sort"

Comment: What is the value of `DEFAULT_OFFSET`? How are you calling the script?

Comment: Default_Offset is a value created in earlier lines of the code. I am calling it via url

Comment: I am trying to use the Yelp API if that helps. This is taken from the sample code and I am trying to implement the different search parameters that they have. They gave location and search term in the example, but I want to be able to use the offset, sort, and category_filter functions!

Comment: https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-api/blob/master/v2/python/sample.py   is where I took my original sample from. I have trouble using other search parameters and have narrowed down the issue to something in the parser.add_arguments. When I added those - thats where I got HTML errors.